# Add subscription and unsubscription date in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

i want to add subscription and unsubscription date in magento newsletter

Comment: Hi and welcome to Magento SE, feel free to check out this post on how to ask a question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask . 
Please provide more information such as **where do you want to show these dates and what are you actually trying to achieve** so we can understand your problem and help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have created custom module for this. Please follow below steps:

**Step : 1**

Create `config.xml` file at location `app/code/local/Abdul/Subscriber/etc` and below code in this file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Abdul_Subscriber>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Abdul_Subscriber>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <abdul_subscriber>
                <class>Abdul_Subscriber_Model</class>
            </abdul_subscriber>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <abdul_subscriber_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Abdul_Subscriber</module>
                </setup>
            </abdul_subscriber_setup>
        </resources>
        <helpers>
            <abdul_subscriber>
                <class>Abdul_Subscriber_Helper</class>
            </abdul_subscriber>
        </helpers>
        <events>
            <newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <abdul_subscriber_save_additional>
                        <class>abdul_subscriber/observer</class>
                        <method>saveAdditionalData</method>
                    </abdul_subscriber_save_additional>
                </observers>
            </newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
        </events>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                <observers>
                    <abdul_subscriber_add_column>
                        <class>abdul_subscriber/observer</class>
                        <method>addGridColumn</method>
                    </abdul_subscriber_add_column>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**Step : 2**

Create `Observer.php` file at location `app/code/local/Abdul/Subscriber/Model` and below code in this file

```
<?php
class Abdul_Subscriber_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function saveAdditionalData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    { 
        $subscriber  = $observer->getSubscriber();
        $subscriber->setSubscriptionDate(date('Y-m-d H:m:s'));
    }

    /**
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function addGridColumn(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getBlock();
        if ($block && $block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid) {
            /** @var Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid $block */
            $block->addColumnAfter('subscription_date', array(
                'header'    => 'Subscription Date',
                'type'      => 'date',
                'index'     => 'subscription_date',
            ), 'status');
        }
    }
}
```

**Step : 3**

Create `Data.php` file at location `app/code/local/Abdul/Subscriber/Helper` and below code in this file

```
<?php
class Abdul_Subscriber_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

**Step : 4**

Create `Abdul_Subscriber.xml` file at location `app/etc/modules` and below code in this file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Abdul_Subscriber>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Abdul_Subscriber>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Note:** After clear all cache in admin `(System -> Cache Management tab)` side and check.

Comment: Filter on the dates in newsletter grid doesn't work.